# Dense subset in $l^{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $p>1$ and $l^{p}=\{\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}:\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|x_n|^p<\infty,x_n \in \mathbb{C}\}$. Then subset $Y=\{\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}:\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_n=0,\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty} \in l^p\}$ is dense in $l^p$ ($l^p$ is Banach space with norm $\|x\|=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|x_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

I've proved this theorem, here's my proof:

Let $x=\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be any sequence from $l^p$. Choose any $r>0$. I'll prove that there exists $y=\{y_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty} \in Y$, that $\|x-y\|$. So let's define such a $y$.

Because $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|x_n|^p<\infty$, we know that exists $N$ that:

$$\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p<\frac{r^{p}}{2^{p+1}}$$

So let $y_n=x_n$ for $n \leq N$ and $y_n=aq^{n-N-1}$ when $n>N$ ($a,q$ will be defined in the future, in addiction $0<q<1$).

Because $y \in Y$, there is:

$$A=\sum_{n=0}^{N}x_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}aq^{n}=\frac{a}{1-q}$$

In addiction we want that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a|^{p}|q|^{pn}<\frac{r^{p}}{2^{p+1}}$$

Note that $a$ has the same sign as $A$, so if $A<0$ we can multiply both sides by $-1$, so we can assume that $A,a>0$ (if $A=0$ then we can simply put $a=0$).

Next by first equation $a=A(1-q)$, so we want that:

$$\frac{A^p(1-q)^p}{1-q^p}<\frac{r^{p}}{2^{p+1}}$$

Let's define continous function $f(x)=\frac{A^p(1-x)^p}{1-x^p}>0$. By simple calculus we can check that it's decreasing function for $x<1$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^-}=0$, so it's possible you fit $q$ that :
$$\frac{A^p(1-q)^p}{1-q^p}<\frac{r^{p}}{2^{p+1}}$$

Finally (beacuse for $p>1$ $|a-b|^p\leq 2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p)$):

$$\|x-y\|^{p}=\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|x_n-y_n|^{p} \leq 2^{p}\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|x_n|^{p}+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|y_n|^{p}\right)<r^p$$

$\textbf{My questions}$ are::Is it correct? Is there any simplier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $x=\{x_1, x_2, \cdots\}$, we take $$x_N = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N, 0,0,0,\cdots\}$$ such that $\|x-x_N\|< \epsilon$

Then take $S =\sum_{n=1}^N x_n$ and define $$y_n = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N,\underbrace{-\frac{S}{n}, -\frac{S}{n}}_{n\text{ times}}, 0,0,0,\cdots\}$$ then $y_n \in Y$ and $\|y_n - x_N\| = n(\frac{S}{n})^p \to 0$.

So $\|y_n - x\| \leq \|x-x_N\|< + \|y_n - x_N\| \leq 2 \epsilon$ when $n$ large enough